# Postgresql: create subscription with create_slot=false if slot exists

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have multiple containers with Postgresql logical replica DBs running on ECS/Fargate. And I wanted to ask if someone know if there is a possibility to create a subscription like this (very pseudo code):

```
IF REPLICATION SLOT my_subscription EXISTS:
    CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_subscription CONNECTION [...]
    WITH (create_slot=false);
ELSE:
    CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_subscription CONNECTION [...]
    WITH (create_slot=true);
```

That would be very helpful for starting and or restarting DB containers.

EDIT: The subscription is in the init.sql of the Docker containers, so that the subscription is created at the start-up of each container.

Comment: Simply try one, and when it fails, try the other.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  Well, yes that would be a possibility if that would be manually managed DBs, but as I wrote, they are running on Fargate which means that I have to edit the init.sql, build a new image, tag and push it... or create all subscriptions manually...  there must be a better solution :)

Comment: What are you using to run the SQL script. `psql`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I use the official postgres12 Docker image[1] and, yes I think psql is used to run the init script.                         
[1] https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `DO` statement and catch the error:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_subscription ...;
EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_object THEN
   CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_subscription ...
      WITH (create_slot = false, slot_name = 'log_slot');
END;$$;
```

Comment: Cool! Thx a lot! I quickly check this

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that there are only pg_replication_slots on the main db. On the replica its an empty table.

Comment: There is no way to find out with a query on the standby if there is a replication slot. Why don't you use a `DO` statement?

Comment: Alright this works perfectly :) Thx a lot. I did not think of this as I am not too familiar with the exception handling in postgres.